# Inner class with namedtuple()

Tags: python, python-3.x, data-conversion

I am trying to use `collections.namedtuple` to convert a dictionary to a python object.

```
import Zabbix

class Foo:

  def bar(self):
    collections.namedtuple('Zabbix.Request',['b','c'])
```

which results in a

```
ValueError: Type names and field names must be valid identifiers: 'Zabbix.Request'
```

My simple fix was to just extend the inner class inside Foo

```
import Zabbix

class Foo:

  class Request(Zabbix.Request):
    pass

  def bar(self):
    collections.namedtuple('Request',['b','c'])
```

Is there a better way? Currently using python 3.4

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do here? None of this makes any sense.

Comment: Your `bar` method doesn't return the namedtuple, so it does nothing.  What are you trying to achieve by putting "Zabbix.Request" as the name of the namedtuple?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't give a type the name `Zabbix.Request` because that's invalid syntax (e.g., `class Zabbix.Request:`). As such you also can't create a `namedtuple` with that name.

Your modified code is not equivalent to the first code sample: you're now creating a `namedtuple` with `Request` as name. This is allowed as `Request` would be a valid identifier for a type.